# Nested many to many relationship prisma

Tags: prisma, prisma2

I use prisma and create a many to many relationship between two tables as follows

```js
model Post {
  id         Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  categories CategoriesOnPosts[]
}

model Category {
  id    Int                 @id @default(autoincrement())
  posts CategoriesOnPosts[]
}

model CategoriesOnPosts {
  post       Post     @relation(fields: [postId], references: [id])
  postId     Int
  category   Category @relation(fields: [categoryId], references: [id])
  categoryId Int 

  @@id([postId, categoryId])
}
```

But I need that third table ( CategoriesOnPosts ) to be in a many-to-many relationship with another table ( likes )

```js
model CategoriesOnPosts {
  likes     likes[]
}

model likes {}
```

**Is this possible, and how to make this relationship between CategoriesOnPosts  and likes ?**

thank you